# Cannot shrink the window of WebKit2Gtk

Tags: gtk, webkitgtk

I am trying to compile the source code of WebKit2Gtk based on https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/WebKitGtk/ProgrammingGuide/Tutorial

Then I found that, I can only expand the window, but not shrink. I wonder which property can be set to allow shrinking?

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake using the wrong pkg-config, which is 2.4.8. If using 2.4.8, WebKitWebView has to be embedded in the GtkScrolledWindow. If using 2.6, WebKitWebView is scrollable by itself. Then it does not required to be embedded in the GtkScrolledWindow.